# WooCommerce: Limit shipping on specific product to one Country

Tags: woocommerce

Certain products on my site can only be shipped USA wide and not to Canada (As is allowed by the Geozones I created). I need to somehow implement this on my site (prevent users from shipping certain items to Canada.) I am not well versed in coding and would prefer changing a few lines of code or ideally using an extension to achieve this.

Thank you